# integrated email in and out system in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, email

i have a cms / portal rails app and i want to allow users to send and receive emails from within the application.  I want to do this so that i can record and show all activity / communications from and to users contacts.

I have done this in another site but had problems displaying and creating html emails within the site.  Styles can get mixed into the sites sytles, wysiwyg editors are not the best etc.

Any one have any experience, suggestions or help they can give me.

thanks 
rick

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite complex topic. I have been working to integrate a similar system for the last 3 months, and I have to say there are countless of issues dealing with email parts, contents and encodings.

Sending emails is a really straightforward problem. Receiving, parsing and manipulating emails is much more complex.

I can suggest you to start exploring the [Mail](http://rubygems.org/gems/mail) Gem. It provides some very goods methods to compose, deliver and parse emails in Ruby.